# Background theme of error of EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I sent an error with setError in my EditText, how can i change the theme of my editText to get a black theme error:

Here is my code:

```
EditText et_email = bla...;  
et_email.setError(mRes.getString(R.string.invalid_email));
```

I get some like this:

[image]

I need some like this.
[image]

Comment: maybe use `Light` theme, like : `Theme.DeviceDefault.Light`

Comment: Late answer, but using Theme.AppCompat.Light results in the black background.
Which theme are you using that results in that nice white background bordered by red?

Answer (score 1):

what theme are you using ? I think the right is
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
the keyword here is the Light, because it seems you are using the dark.

Comment: I use Theme.AppCompat , and Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen , i change to DarkActionBar but without results.

Comment: Then: Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
I found here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml